# Using polar coordinates, evaluate the integral which gives the area which lies in the first quadrant between the circles

Tags: calculus

Using polar coordinates, evaluate the integral which gives the area which lies in the first quadrant between the circles:
$$x^2 + y^2 = 16$$
and
$$x^2 -4x + y^2 = 0$$

My solution:
$r$ is between $4\cos(x)$ and 4
the angle is between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$
and then take the double integral with these limits and $r\ dr\ d \theta$
but I keep getting the wrong answer. Sorry I don't know how to write the question using the correct format.

Comment: I notice that you've been here about a month and haven't accepted any answers.  You might want to take a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: sorry. I did not know about that. Thank you for telling me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach: evaluate the areas separately then subtract.  The area of the big one is simply $$\int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^4 r\ drd\theta$$

The area of the smaller circle is $$\int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{4\cos(\theta)} r\ drd\theta$$

---

Also, notice that it's easy to check your solution because the two boundaries are parts of circles so you should be able to easily figure out what the answer should be without even using calculus.